# Keeping a process always running even when M1 Mac is sleeping

Tags: mac, sleep-wake, apple-silicon

I would like to keep a process "always on" as some specific iOS apps (such as navigation or music apps) are able to, even when the Mac is put to sleep. Since it's an M1 Mac it seems to me that the hardware itself should easily enable it, but I can't find any way to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Sleep is a state in which processes can't be run and the computer is semi-shutdown. It's entirely analogous with human sleep. "I'd like to write my essay while I'm asleep."

Comment: @benwiggy I'm not really sure about this in the case of M1 Macs. Apple presented the M1 processor as "always on" (https://imarc.co.uk/2021/03/02/m1-macs-really-are-always-on/) so it seems sleep is now more comparable to iOS devices sleep than it it to Intel Macs sleep.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to run user selected processes or applications while macOS is asleep.

Some specific processes can be run during sleep, through [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40773/mac), but these are limited to Apple's applications.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I wonder if it would be possible to develop a kernel extension for such use cases. Thank you for your answer

Comment: General kernel extensions were [deprecated in macOS 10.15](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec8e454101b/web). Without Apple's support of third party processes during sleep, it will not be possible.